# Particular integrals question

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)$ be a continuous function, and $a>0$. Prove $$\int_{-a}^af(x^2)dx=2\int_0^af(x^2)dx $$

This seems trivial.. I'm simply not sure how to solve it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the $\int_{-a}^{a}$ has two bits to it, $\int_{-a}^0 + \int_0^a$. The second one is half of the RHS. Can you see why the first one doubles up? *Hint*: Change of variables.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

Show that $g(x) = f(x^2)$ is an even function, then it follows that $\int_{-a}^a g(x) dx = 2 \int_0^a g(x) dx$